# Does TIdHTTP.Free also clean up assigned Compressor and IOHandler?

Tags: delphi

I have a `TIdHTTP` object created during runtime, which has its `IOHandler` and `Compression` properties set to objects that are also created during runtime. If I call `Free` on my `TIdHTTP` object, does this automatically free up the `IOHandler` and `Compression` objects assigned to it?

```
function CreateHTTP():TIdHTTP;
begin
  Result := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  Result.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(Result)
  Result.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
end;
```

Elsewhere in the application, this code gets called several times:

```
with CreateHTTP() do begin
  Data := Get('http://google.com');
  Free;
end;
```

Would this result in a memory leak of the Compressor and IOHandler, or are they automatically destroyed?

Just in case it is not automatically destroyed, I have added an override for the `Destroy` method like such:

```
destructor TIdHTTP.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(Compressor) then
    Compressor.Free;
  if Assigned(IOHandler) then
    IOHandler.Free;

  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lifetime of an object is tied to the lifetime of its owner; if an object is freed, it will free all its children. If you do not pass an owner when creating an object, you are responsible for freeing the object yourself if it is no longer needed.

This means that in your specific example, the `Compressor` will be freed with the client (because you pass the `TIdHttp` instance as owner), while the `IOHandler` will be leaked (because you pass nil as owner, and don't free it yourself). Passing `Result` as owner to both will render your destructor obsolete. Also, don't get into the habit of writing code "just in case". The behavior is deterministic, so you if you don't know if it's one way or another you should strive to find out, instead of just planning for both ;)

The code you showed has a bigger potential memory leak though: If an exception is raised during the `Get`-Request, the `TIdHttp` instance itself will be leaked (along with the `Compressor`). In fact this does happen if you run the code as is, because Google issues a redirect, and the client is not set to handle this redirect. You should wrap the code in `try-finally` like so:

```
with CreateHTTP do begin
  try
    Get('http://google.com');
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

You also want to do proper exception handling, but I'm assuming you left that out for brevity.

Finally, when in doubt about memory leaks, using the built-in FastMM in FullDebugMode will report and log all memory leaks on shutdown. This would have helped you spot the memory leak in this instance, but is advised in general to also spot the leaks you have not thought about yet ;)

Comment: Thanks for the well detailed explanation. I will look in to FastMM. I do use exception handling in the actual code, I just trimmed it down to the parts I thought are immediately relevant.

Comment: On a side note, you do not need to create an SSLlOHandler unless you are accessing HTTPS urls (which your example is not). And if you do, and are using an up-to-date version of Indy, [you don't need to create the SSLIOHandler](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.EN.aspx) unless you need to customize its settings.